# Wpf ComboBox loop on reload

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a combobox:

```
<ComboBox 
    SelectedValuePath="Key" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Value.ModuleName" 
    controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="All" 
    Height="2" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}" 
    commands:PropertyChangeBehavior.Command="{Binding ModuleCommand}" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedModule, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
    >
```

Basically logic is simple, but on one moment I am clearing that control and fill it with new data, problem is it falls into infinity loop, for example i select item from combo box, command fires executes code and refills combo box with new data, so new data fires command etc etc.

Is there a way to solve this.

My apologies, Item source is a :

```
    private Dictionary<string, ModulesModel> modules;
    public Dictionary<string, ModulesModel> Modules
    {
        get => modules;
        set
        {
            modules = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can we see the c# code?

Comment: You only can to manually check if value was set by you or by user. Before executing the refill set some field to "true" and check this value in your command (so it won't execute if that field was true). After refilling set back that field to "false"

Comment: "...on one moment I am clearing that control and fill it with new data". Where is this code?

Comment: `Dictionary` is not an Observable, use `ObservableDictionary`, then you will want to ensure you've properly implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your ViewModel, Once you have this, then when `ObservableCollection` is updated, the changes will reflect in the UI (combo box) through the data binding.  You should not be hard coding a 'clear and fill' combo box

Comment: "Basically logic is simple". Saying "basic" and/or "simple" doesn't tell the reader anything about what your code actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, the VM's `Modules` property is an `ObservableCollection`. The easy way to solve the problem then is to check if the new data is the same before you update its content (which is most probably the case).
But I'd look deeper into the semantics and try to understand why item selection is triggering data updating. Normally you don't need it.

Update:

Here's what I suggested before, how you could break the loop.

```
private Dictionary<string, ModulesModel> modules;
public Dictionary<string, ModulesModel> Modules
{
    get => modules;
    set
    {
        if (!AreEqual(modules, value))
        {
            modules = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation of `AreEqual` can be smth. like this:

```
static bool AreEqual<T1, T2>(Dictionary<T1, T2> left, Dictionary<T1, T2> right) =>
    left?.Count == right?.Count &&
    left != null &&
    (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(left.Keys, right.Keys) &&
    Enumerable.SequenceEqual(left.Values, right.Values));
```